# Why Java Swing Pinned Apps Not Opening In Place On The Taskbar In Windows 10?

Tags: java, windows, swing

I have a Java desktop application developed using Swing, and deployed using Launch4J.

If I pin the Java desktop application to Windows 10 taskbar, and then launch it, the app is not opening in place on the taskbar. To illustrate the problem, this is how it looks like.

### There are 2 icons appear in Taskbar. 1 icon for launcher, another icon for current active running app

[image]

---

I expect there should be only 1 icon. This is how the pinned app Netbeans look like, if it is launched.

### Only 1 icon appears in Taskbar. 1 icon for both launcher and current active running app

[image]

---

**Do you have idea what goes wrong with my Java Swing application deployment? Why 2 icons are being shown on the taskbar?**

I am using Launch4J (http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to build the EXE via the following XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>gui</headerType>
  <jar>c:\yocto\jstock\dist\jstock.jar</jar>
  <outfile>c:\yocto\jstock\installer\windows\jstock.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir></chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon>c:\yocto\jstock\installer\windows\chart.ico</icon>
  <jre>
    <path></path>
    <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
    <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
    <minVersion>1.7.0</minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
    <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
    <initialHeapSize>64</initialHeapSize>
    <maxHeapSize>512</maxHeapSize>
    <opt>-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=false</opt>
  </jre>
  <versionInfo>
    <fileVersion>1.1.8.5</fileVersion>
    <txtFileVersion>1.1.8.5</txtFileVersion>
    <fileDescription>JStock - Stock Market Software</fileDescription>
    <copyright>Yan Cheng Cheok &lt;yancheng.cheok@gmail.com&gt;</copyright>
    <productVersion>1.1.8.5</productVersion>
    <txtProductVersion>1.1.8.5</txtProductVersion>
    <productName>JStock - Stock Market Software</productName>
    <companyName>Yan Cheng Cheok &lt;yancheng.cheok@gmail.com&gt;</companyName>
    <internalName>jstock</internalName>
    <originalFilename>jstock.exe</originalFilename>
    <trademarks></trademarks>
    <language>ENGLISH_US</language>
  </versionInfo>
</launch4jConfig>
```

Comment: My guess, and it's only a guess because you haven't provided a [mre] showing us your code, is that your application has two `JFrames`, or that the first icon is the launcher and the second is your application.  Eclipse has a launcher icon and a separate application icon, as one example.

Comment: The NSI file creates the installer - but the installer is not relevant for your question. The question is how you build the exe file using launch4j.

Comment: @ThomasKläger U r right. I am confusing myself. I am using Launch4J to build the EXE. I have updated my question.